# Как сериализовать/десериализовать экземпляры классов в файл

Tags: c#, сериализация

Проблема следующая: Имеется три класcа:

```
class Class1 
{
// Список переменных и методов
}

class Class2
{
// Список переменных и методов
}

class Class3
{
// Список переменных и методов
}

// Создаю экземпляры классов

Сlass1 object1 = new Class1();
Сlass2 object2 = new Class2();
Сlass2 object3 = new Class3();
```

Вопрос: Как сериализовать/десериализовать экземпляры классов в один файл?

Comment: Задавал подобный вопрос несколько ранее, там есть информация по вашей проблеме. Мне, к сожалению, немного более сложное пришлось придумать.

[Сериализация][1]


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/300080/c-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD-xml-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB

Answer (score 1):

Так ведь ничего сложного

```
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new  FileOutputStream(file,true));
out.writeObject(object1);
out.writeObject(object2);
out.writeObject(object3);
out.close();
```

При этом Class1, Class2, Class3 должны имплементировать интерфейс Serializable

Comment: Нужно реализовать это на C#

Comment: Тогда вот примерчик - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4abbf6k0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx